# Recorrer completamente un folder hasta que no haya mas archivos

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs

Saludos a todos a todos,

Les explicare de forma rapida lo que me sucede,
Estoy creando un sistema de exploracion de archivos con Node.js y el modulos File System, el problema es que quiero recorrer un directorio hasta su fin, es decir que si dentro de este directorio hay un folder que lo recorra y si dentro de este tambien hay un directorio que tambien lo recorra y asi hasta que finalize todo el folder.
He intentado con **bucles** y con la funcion de **File System de .isDirectory()**, pero sin embargo no encuentro la solucion.
Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Podrías compartir el código que has intentado para que así podamos ayudarte? Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta de acuerdo a las [recomendaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e incluyas un [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has realizado.

Answer (score 0):

Esto ya esta preguntado en OS, puedes leer el post original en ingles [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511789/looping-through-files-in-a-folder-node-js)

Pero como resumen, puedes utilizar la libreria `fs` de node para trabajar con archivos. Para saber mas sobre trabajar con archivos en nodeJS puedes leer la [documentación](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)